# C++ code: count not working

Tags: c++

I wanted to ask, i formulated this code to solve a question, but count does not seem to provide the right value.

Any advice.Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int count;
    for(int a=1;a<125;a++)
        for(int m=1;m<125;m++)
            for(int n=1;n<125;n++)
            {
                if(a*(m+n+2)==249-m)
                {
                    cout<<"a = "<<a<<" m = "<<m<<" n = "<<n<<"\n";
                    count=count+1;
                }
            }
            cout<<"count = "<<count<<"\n";
            getch();
}
```

Comment: Initialize count value as count=0

Comment: `<iostream.h>` is not a standard header, and neither is `void main` a legal signature.

Comment: @chris are u kiiding me???

Comment: You need `<iostream>` and `int main()` (or version with args, but it must return `int`. This is, assuming a standards compliant compiler.

Answer (score 6):

You do not init the `count`. Remember to set `int count = 0;`.

Your compiler will warn you about this and save you the trouble of debugging or asking if you only let it. (from @chris)

Comment: Teach a man to fish. Your compiler will warn you about this and save you the trouble of debugging or asking if you only let it.

Comment: @chris: it warns only if you have a good compiler OR set it properly.

Comment: @MatthieuM., The latter is what I meant by "If you just let it". It's right there at your fingertips. And I thought this warning has been there on like every compiler in the last decade.

Comment: @chris: I understand the idea, however many people just do not pass any warning flag to a compiler, and thus a compiler which does not provide a "good set of warnings" by default is silent...

Comment: @MatthieuM., Yeah, it's a shame. They should have at least `-Wall` on by default.

Comment: @chris: that's why I love Clang so much, the bar to put a warning in place is that it should have so few false positives that it can be on by default; and thus out of the box you get useful warnings (and of course since they display the name of the warning it's easy to turn off if you really want to).